# Optimize request in the FOR loop

Tags: django, optimization, orm

How can I optimize the following request to eliminate loop? Codes count is several hundred, so I get several hundreds database queries, which is unacceptable.

```
n = 3
result = []
codes = Target.objects.filter(code__in=['ABC', 'CDE', ...])

for code in codes:
    result.append(Data.objects.select_related('target')
                              .filter(target__code=code)
                              .values('spec', 'spec_type')
                              .order_by('-spec')[:n])
```

Models:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(Target)
    spec_type = models.CharField()
    spec = models.FloatField()

class Target(models.Model):
    code = models.TextField(db_index=True)
```

Comment: What should be the result: currently you are constructing a list of `QuerySet`s. Do you want a "flat" list of items? For a list of `Queryset`s, there is not much optimization that can be done.

Comment: I've dropped some logic which converts Querysets to dicts, and the final result is as follows: [ {'ABC': [{'spec': 'Spec 123', 'spec_type': 'Spec Type A'}, {'spec': 'Spec 456', 'spec_type': 'Spec Type B'}] }, 'CDE': ... ]. So its the dict with key 'code' and value - list of two dict which are data, retrieved by the Data.objects.... query.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to retrieve the `codes` as a `QuerySet` to enumerate over. We can directly work with the list of codes.

If you want to construct a `QuerySet` that contains all the given elements, you can make a `QuerySet` with union that will fetch these objects. In that case this can be done with [**`.union(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union):

```
codes = ['ABC', 'CDE']
n = 3
result = Data.objects.none().union(
    *[
      Data.objects.filter(target__code=code).values('spec', 'spec_type').order_by('-spec')[:n]
      for code in codes
    ],
    all=True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Willem Van Onsem said, you don't need to get get a queryset of your `Target` objects since you already seem to have the codes that you want. Just store the codes in a variable and then you can do a django query using that list.

```
codes = ['ABC', 'CDE', ...]

result = Data.objects.filter(target__code__in = codes)
```

This query should return all `Data` objects of which the related `Target` object's code is in the list `codes`.

Comment: I've tried this query first and it gets me only data for the first code 'ABC' for some reason.

Comment: Then are you sure your values in the codes list match what is in your database? I have used this query with my own project's models and it works perfectly.

Comment: Sure I do. One interesting thing: if I omit [:n] slicing in the end of the query, I get all of the data for each code, so I guess it's something to do with the logic of subsetting.

Comment: Yeah, if you put `[:n]` at the end of the filter call then the result would only have the first n entries in the queryset returned from the filter.